# nant mail issues

Tags: email, nant

Can anyone please suggest me how we could configure the sending of mails through nant.I had even gone through the link but i was unsucessfull.

thanks and regards
maddy

Answer (score 1):

Something like this is what you would use.

```
<target name="sendmail">
    <mail
        from=“NAnt@myCompany.com“
        tolist=“${distribution_list}“
        subject="${mailsubject}" 
        mailhost="${smtpServer}"
        message="${mailbody}"
        verbose="true"
     >
        <attachments>
            <include name="${buildroot}/build.log" />
        </attachments>
    </mail>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample build file. The solution is not very elegant but it works. All it does is logs a file and before sending email flush it and makes a copy of it to attach it in email.

Note: there are some help links in code which i used while writing my own build file.

```
<description>Sample Build Scripts</description>


<property name="nant.onsuccess" value="success" />
<property name="nant.onfailure" value="failure" />
<property name="tolist" value="youremail@email.com" />
<property name="cclist" value="youremail@email.com" />
<property name="emailsubject" value="" />   


<target name="build" depends="init">

    YOUR ACTUAL BUILD CODE GOES HERE

</target>





<target name="init">

    <echo>
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TASK : INITIALIZE
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    </echo>

    <loadtasks assembly="nantcontrib-0.85/bin/NAnt.Contrib.Tasks.dll" />     
    <!-- http://www.basilv.com/psd/blog/2007/how-to-add-logging-to-ant-builds -->
    <tstamp>            
        <formatter property="timestamp" pattern="yyMMdd_HHmm"/>
    </tstamp>   

    <property name="build.log.filename" value="build_${timestamp}.log"/>

    <echo message="build.log.filename: ${build.log.filename}" />

    <record name="${build.log.dir}/${build.log.filename}"   action="Start" level="Verbose"/>        

    <echo message="Build logged to ${build.log.filename}"/>

    <echo message="Build Start at: ${datetime::now()}" />

</target>


<!--http://www.mail-archive.com/nant-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02485.html-->
<target name="success" depends="successresult,sendemail">     
     <echo>${emailsubject}</echo>   
</target>

  <!--http://www.mail-archive.com/nant-users@lists.sourceforge.net/msg02485.html-->
<target name="failure" depends="failureresult,sendemail">
     <echo>${emailsubject}</echo>           
</target>


<target name="successresult" > 
    <echo>
        BUILD FAILED .  CHANGE SUBJECT
    </echo>
    <property name="emailsubject" value="Web Integration DEV Build : SUCCESS !!!" />            
</target>


<target name="failureresult" >      

    <echo>      
    BUILD FAILED . CHANGE SUBJECT       
    </echo>
    <echo message="Task Start at: ${datetime::now()}" />

    <property name="emailsubject" value="Web Integration DEV Build : FAILED !!!  :)" />   
</target>


<target name="sendemail" >

    <echo>      
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SENDING EMAIL
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    </echo>
    <echo message="Task Start at: ${datetime::now()}" />

    <echo>${emailsubject}</echo>    
    <echo>Sending Email</echo>
    <echo>Attaching File : ${build.log.dir}/email_${build.log.filename}</echo>
    <echo>Attaching File : ${path.vsshelper.log}/logs/email_${build.log.getlistoffiles}</echo>

    <!-- Flush is very important before you copy -->
    <record name="${build.log.dir}/${build.log.filename}"       action="Flush" level="Verbose"/>
    <sleep milliseconds="1000" />
    <!-- make a copy -->
    <copy file= "${build.log.dir}/${build.log.filename}" tofile="${build.log.dir}/email_${build.log.filename}" />   

    <mail   
            from="${email.from}"
            tolist="${email.to}"
            mailhost="${email.host}"
            message="${emailsubject}"
            subject="${emailsubject}"
    >             
            <attachments>
                <include name="${build.log.dir}/email_${build.log.filename}" />                 
                <include name="${path.vsshelper.log}/logs/email_${build.log.getlistoffiles}" />
            </attachments>             
    </mail>

</target>
```