# How to make NAnt send an email using a real account

Tags: nant, nant-task

First of all, I have already seen this post: [nant mail issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1067403/nant-mail-issues) but the only answer is not satisfactory (i.e.: doesn't work for me).

I am using NAnt to get latest version of source, upgrade version of the libraries and application, build the application, build the setups... all the usual things, I bet. I would like NAnt to send an email to some people confirming the conclusion of the build process; I've already checked the official (pretty ugly, IMHO) [documentation for the  task](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/mail.html), but the example, once copied and customized, doesn't work.

This are the NAnt target and task I'm using:

```
<target name="sendMail" >
    <mail 
        from="MyUserName@gmail.com" 
        tolist="user1@provider1.com;user2@provider1.com" 
        subject="Subject of email" 
        mailhost="smtp.gmail.com"
        message="Your new release is ready!">
    </mail>
</target>
```

The error message I get is:

> 530 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS
>   command first.

It looks like that the task was designed for use by an account whose provider doesn't need authentication; but what can I do if I must use an external smtp server which requires authentication (telling my boss I need an smtp server in house is not an option)?

Can anybody help/teach me?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 9):

Looking at the [code currently in the nant-trunk](http://nant.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nant/nant/src/NAnt.Core/Tasks/MailTask.cs?view=markup), the nant task doesn't feature authentication.
According to this [knowledge base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555287/en-us), it can be done even with the System.Web.Mail class which nant is currently using, but the nant task doesn't expose the necessary properties. 
So to answer your question, I think you have the following choices:

- add support for authentication to the current nant task via the technique described in the knowledge base article (be sure to add 
  "http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl", "true"
  to the  message fields), re-compile it and use it via the [loadtasks](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/loadtasks.html)-task
- create your own email task via the [Smtp client class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.credentials%28v=VS.80%29.aspx) (since the System.Web.Mail might be  deprecated for a reason) and use it via the loadtasks-task.

**Update:**
I just changed the implementation of the mail task and [submitted a patch to the NAnt guys at sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3229038&group_id=31650&atid=402870). If you are interested you can download the file there, so you don't have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

that would be a great value-add to the NantContrib project. I am sure many would benefit if you could rebuild that and submit it.