# TeamCity and NAnt: With what to send build success / failed email?

Tags: continuous-integration, nant, teamcity

I want to send an email if the build fails to the developers, with the fail details. I'm also wants to send a success email to the project admins, etc with the address to the new test application.

What is the proper tool to send the actual mail, TeamCity or NAnt?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [Nant to send email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1079293/how-to-make-nant-send-an-email-using-a-real-account), but TeamCity is more appropriate, as it can provide a **centralized** place [for notifications](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD5/Customizing%20Notifications%20(in%20TeamCity%205.1)), including [emails](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD5/EMail%20Notifier%20Tab).

[image]
<sub>(source: [jetbrains.net](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/download/attachments/15804911/sconfEmailNotifierTab.png))</sub>

> TeamCity provides a **wide range of notification possibilities** to keep developers informed about the status of their projects.
>   Notifications can be sent by:
>
> - e-mail,
> - Jabber/XMPP instant messages or
> - can be displayed in the IDE (with the help of TeamCity plugins) or
> - the Windows system tray (using TeamCity Windows tray notifier).
>
> Each user can select the events to receive notifications for on My Settings And Tools page. The notification messages can be customized globally on per-server basis.

So it is not just about how to send the mail, but also how to manage the notification process, from the server *and from the client* perspective.